# How to make a command outside the media query not run when the media query is activated?

Tags: css, media-queries

So i have this navbar and I just set my last element to have the margin-right: 0
but when media query runs, I see my navbar pop up and see the last item has margin-right: 0 applied as well and I dont want that. How can I fix this? I am not sure if I have to insert all the code here

```
.navbar {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: auto;
    background: rgb(255, 236, 65);
}

.list {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.list-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.list-item:nth-child(4) {
    margin-right: 0;
}


@media all and (max-width: 650px) {
    .navbar {
       flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .list {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        display: none;
    }

    .list-item {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 45px;
    }

    .menu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 35px;
        right: 42px;
    }

    .active {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want it to be?

Comment: I want when my media query runs my margin-right: 0 to not be applied on the last child basically

Comment: Hav you tried doing that margin setting within its own media query?

Comment: Well I used margin-right: 40px in the media query and it centers the last element looking good enough but I was wondering if there was another way and I'm not sure if this is the best/optimum solution to solve it

Comment: I wasn't thinking of changing the existing media query but of putting the margin-right: 0 setting into its own media query.

Comment: I tried that but that did not work

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
I Hope it will work

```
.navbar {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: auto;
  background: rgb(255, 236, 65);
}

.list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.list-item:nth-child(4) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

@media all and (max-width: 650px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .list {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    /* display: none; */
  }

  .list-item {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
  }
  .list-item:nth-child(4) {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }

  .menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    right: 42px;
  }

  .active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this method as I said in the comment above but I thought there is a better way to do it